# How to add two 3D meshes to get single mesh in python

Tags: python-3.x, open3d, bpy, trimesh, pymesh

I'm playing with some mesh operations.
Suppose we have two meshes, one human head mesh and another one is human body.
we just have to add head to body so that the end result is one single complete human body
mesh.
I think it can be done using python-blender but i'm not that much expert in blender scripting.
May be another python library can be useful.
Please recommend some way out.

Tried join operation in blender. But it's working as expected because we want to add the two meshes
at specific location i.e. neck.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean operation on meshes is a novelty of open3d v0.16, you could take a look at it :
[http://www.open3d.org/blog/][link]

Comment: Thanks Damocis, Let me check it.